# Is it possible to build a map in a MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to build a map as part of a group operation in MongoDB but am having no luck.

My documents are structured as follows :

```
type : artist,
artist : David Bowie,
song : "Starman"
```

For example as part of my aggregation I want to group all "types" and have a map containing the artists name as the key and the songs as a value. For an output like :

```
[_id : artist, myMap : ["David Bowie" : "Starman"]]
```

But I'm not sure if this is even possible. I've tried using Mongos $push operation but it doesn't like it when I try to push a map. Has anyone attempted this before?

Heres the query I tried :

```
 db.music.aggregate(
                 {
                   $group: {
                             _id: "$type",
                             myMap : { $push: {"$artist" : "$song" }}
                           }
                 }
              )
```

Comment: This may be close to what you are looking for: `db.music.aggregate(
 {$project : {
  "type" : 1,
  foo : { "artist" : "$artist" , "song" : "$song"}
 }},
 {$group : {
  "_id" : "$type",
  "map" : {$push: "$foo" }
 }}
)`

Comment: @orid Thank you..Mark this as an answer and I'll accept. Works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be close to what you are looking for:

```
db.music.aggregate( 
    {$project : 
        { 
          "type" : 1, 
          foo : { "artist" : "$artist" , "song" : "$song"} 
        }
    }, 
    {$group : 
        { "_id" : "$type", "map" : {$push: "$foo" }}
    } 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not do that with MongoDB. But there is a [Jira Ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947) asking for that feature.